# Rails 5, does the create method run even if model validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app.

I have a order controller with a create method that saves new orders which come from a form submit. One field of the order is the ZIP code and in my create method I use the ZIP code to calculate the shipping cost.

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  shipping = calculateShipping(@order.zip)
  ...
end
```

I need the zip code for every order so I have a validation in my Order model

```
validates :zip, presence: true
```

If I now submit an order without ZIP code I get an error from the calculateShipping because it's missing the ZIP code.

1. I thought that the validation runs first and does not even call the create method if the form is not valid. Why do I still get the error? What can I do to solve it?
2. Should I put the shipping cost calculation in the model? How would that look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this: try to create the order from the params, and redisplay the new form (with errors) if unsuccessful.

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  @order.calc_shipping
  if @order.save
    redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

In your Order model, you could have a method to calculate the shipping

```
def calc_shipping
  self.shipping = ...
end
```